# Craft Commerce: How to manage different prices with one product?

Tags: plugins, plugin-craftcommerce, events, ecommerce

I am looking for a solution that would allow me to sell events tickets within Craft. I'm am currently making a prototype with Craft Commerce plugin for this project, but I am already facing a major problem.

When creating a new product, I can set a ticket price + a total number of tickets available at this price. When using variants, I can define multiple tickets + a total of available tickets under each price. But it does not seems possible to synchronize a total number of available tickets with different price options (full price and other at reduced fare).

How can I do ? Is it possible to set the total number of tickets available outside of variants, such as the variants would be only used to set the price ?

Answer (score 2):

Craft Commerce support has answered to my question :

> Currently Craft Commerce can not have a stock counter that covers more
>   than one variant. The default product+variant system is not designed
>   for tickets. We hope to see a ticket 'Purchasable' plugin in the
>   future. You can request this feature [here](http://feedback.craftcms.com/forums/295386-commerce/filters/top).
>
> If you have some plugin experience, you could get around this issue
>   you described with a plugin that updates the stock of other variants
>   when someone purchases a variant using the onOrderVariant event. You
>   would likely need to know the relationships between SKUs for the
>   different variants within your plugin, and deduct the stock from the
>   related variants like so:
>
> ```
> craft()->db->createCommand()->update('commerce_variants',
>   ['stock' => new \CDbExpression('stock - :qty', [':qty' => $theQty ])],
>   'id = :variantId',
>   [':variantId' => $variantId]);
> ```
>
> Check out the [Stock Notifier plugin](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/CommerceStockNotifier/blob/master/commercestocknotifier/CommerceStockNotifierPlugin.php) as it matches closely to the
>   events you would need to use.